# How to place a button in the center of div of dynamic size

Tags: css, html, button, alignment

I have this code:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="inner">
            <div class="line">information1</div>
            <div class="line">hyperlink1</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="line">information2</div>
            <div class="line">hyperlink2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="line">information3</div>
            <div class="line">hyperlink3</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="line">information4</div>
            <div class="line">hyperlink4</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="send" class="button"/>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.outer
{
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}    
.list
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}    
.inner
{
    display: table-row;
    padding: 5px;
}    
.line
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}    
.button
{
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
}
```

the output is: [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mDHBX/)

Now i want to place the button in the center of the 'outer' div no matter what is the width.

example: i want the button to be in center even for: [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/puM2B/). without having to change the css each time the div size changes. Even if the 'outer' div is dynamic, the button should be in the center.

thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This achieves what you're looking for in a simple, succinct, way:

```
.button {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to give the button a specific width and then you can use automatic margins

```
.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/CrHyd/

Comment: this will break if text inside button is too long to be fit inside 100px

Comment: ya. if the word is very long. it is not showing the end part.

Comment: You don't need the width, that is true. 100px were just an example based on the code he gave. When was the last time 'Send' needed more then 100px?

Comment: ya. i dont have enough reputation to vote up. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do this. I prefer using percentages like so:

```
input[type="submit"]{
    min-width:20%;
    max-width:20%;
    margin:0% 39% 0% 40%; //margin-right = 39% to stop errors
}
```

Other people prefer a `margin:auto` approach but personally I've never found this to work. Other methods include using `floats` but I don't agree with this property as it mis aligns other elements in some browsers.

Using top and left will cause errors as you've not specified a position type other than default (static).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
.outer {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
```

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mDHBX/6/)

Comment: i wanted it to be in table format and i wanted the button in center of div. the above css puts it in center of the page.

Comment: then wrap the submit button in some other div and apply this style to it with width:100%; fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mDHBX/9/

Answer (score 0):

Just change `.button` to this, using the [`margin`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) property. (1 line fix)

```
.button
{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle where I made the `.outer` a fixed width of `500px` just to show an example of what [`margin`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) does:

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mDHBX/8/)